# Does the visible part of an iceberg depend on size?

Tags: water, buoyancy, ice

Most people heard that we only see some % of an iceberg above water (10% etc). I suspect the exact % depends on the iceberg's shape (e.g. flat disc vs very narrow cylinder). But, assuming a similar, roughly spherical shape, does this % change with the iceberg's size? If you had roughly spherical icebergs, 1m, 10m, 100m & 1000m (that's a big one) in diameter, would you always see the same % above water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perfectly spherical ball of some uniform density $\rho_{ball}$ in water of uniform density $\rho_{water}$ would have the exact same percentage above water regardless of the radius of the ball.

However, in reality it's not quite that simple because the water has different density at different depths, therefore a larger ball of let's say $1000$m radius would have a larger percentage visible due to the colder water at the bottom giving a larger pressure gradient than what a smaller ball would feel close to the surface. Also in reality the iceberg does not have uniform density making it even more complex, but on average it's said that roughly 1/10th of an iceberg is above water.

Comment: +1. But density changes in ocean water are primarily due to salinity and temperature. The salinity may vary for example because water evaporates from the surface, or melted ice mixes with ocean water and dilutes it, That said, all these effects are small.

Comment: Thanks. So the graph of the visible fraction (x = diameter, y=visible fraction) would start at 0.1 for small bergs, then increase slightly for bigger bergs. Presumably the increase would be non linear: total buoyancy depends on volume, volume depends on the cube of the diameter?

Comment: @MrSparkly that's right. As density of the water increases with depth the visible fraction of an iceberg would increase. Exactly how y (visible fraction) would look for increasing x (diameter) I don't know, I guess that depends on the density profile of the water. That shouldn't be too hard to calculate though using buoyancy force, but I'll have to get back to that later.

Answer (score 2):

Archimedes’ principle tells us that a floating body displaces its own weight of water. This is regardless of its shape. So a solid body with an average density that is $x\%$ that of the water in which it floats will float with $x\%$ of its volume submerged and $100-x\%$ above the water line.

For an iceberg the proportion that is above the water will depend on the average density of the ice compared with the density of seawater - and the biggest factor of variation here will be the salinity and temperature of the seawater. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceberg) says that a typical iceberg is $90\%$ as dense as the seawater in which it floats, so $10\%$ of the volume of the iceberg will be above the water line.